# How to use replicate-*-db in MySQL replication?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I currently using the following option to replicate the database "db_name"

```
replicate-wild-do-table=db_name.%
```

Now, I added a stored procedure to one of the databases is not not being replicated. This cause my replication to break. and the reason for that after a long research I found that the above option applys on table/view and not procedures and events. The instruction mentioned the following option

```
replicate-*-db
```

But I am not sure How to use it?
I got this information form the following document
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-program-restrictions.html under the "Replication Considerations" heading

Can someone please tell me how to use replicate-*-db to solve the replication problem.

Comment: The documentation under "Replication Considerations" is potentially a bit misleading... or at least oversimplified.  What does `show variables like 'binlog_format';` say on your server?

Comment: it was STATEMENT but I have changed it to MIXED. I have changes it few hours ago actually because i was getting a unsafe write warning in some of my queries

Comment: Unless you have a reason not to use `ROW` I would suggest giving that a try, because the rows changed by a proc *should* replicate on tables matched by the `*wild*` spec if `ROW` events are generated, because the slave has no way of knowing that the row events came from the proc.  With `STATEMENT` the limitations in the docs would definitely apply, and with `MIXED` it's up to the optimizer to choose which format to use on a query-by-query basis, so it's a toss-up, but `ROW` should be a winner.

Comment: I just switched the binlog_format to ROW but not sure what else do I need to do. I tried to stop slave and then start slave. When I execute show slave status I still get the same error on Last_IO_Error

Comment: You will almost certainly need to relaunch your slave from the master.  If replication mis-config results in the two servers having different data, there's no automatic recovery.

Comment: Okay so here is what I did. I tried to set global sql_slave_skip_counter=1; stop slave; start slave; show slave status \G;  after doing it few time it work and I got no more error. But I created a new prosedure to testing and executed it then it started an error again. the error states Could not execute Write_rows event on table db_name HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the event master log   logname.... end_log_pos 402. Not sure what this error and now sure how to solve it.

Comment: every time i create new procedure it cause an error and the replication fails. How can I solve this problem permanently?

Answer (score 0):

It's master-master replication. You have to setup auto_increment_offset and auto_increment_increment options

Comment: Please rephrase to make this an assertive answer. Otherwise it should be a clarification comment. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead